# How to indent HTML tags in Brackets.io editor as in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, indentation, adobe-brackets, auto-indent

I've been currently using the Brackets.io editor, and it has lots of extensions and so on, which is pretty good. Anyway, I couldn't find any extensions to do precisely what I want, so I came here in hope any of you guys could help me.

Well, as you know, on Netbeans, when you type a tag, such as P, the editor closes it, and if you then press ENTER, it automatically auto indents the code as the following:

```
<p>
    Example
</p>
```

Is there a way to do so on Brackets.io, in the same, **same** way?

Thank you all for your attention :)

Comment: No, it wasn't a duplicate, as you can see now that my question was replied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/brackets-emmet) does that.

Typing the following keys `<` `p` `>` `RETURN` `a` does the following :

**Without** Emmet:

```
<p>
a</p>
```

**With** Emmet:

```
<p>
    a
</p>
```

By the way, Emmet is a very cool tool, and you can obtain the same result faster with the following keys :

`p` `TAB` `RETURN` `a`

Comment: It worked perfectly here. Thank you for your answer :)